# Razorpay multiple bank account

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, razorpay

I would like to have the ability to designate a specific account for each payment transaction. For instance, if I choose the first account during the payment process, I would like the corresponding amount to be credited to that particular account. Similarly, if I opt for the second account, the amount should be credited to the second account.

Can anyone help me with that?

I tried Route in Razorpay, but i didn't understood.

Comment: You can create sub-merchant accounts using linked account apis, in razor pay route, after KYC verification, you will get an account id  add that account id and amount as transfer  when you create order